# SQL Server - OR clause in join confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table structure like below

```
Package

PACK_ID | DESCR | BRAND_ID
  1     | Shoes |   20
  2     | Cloths|  NULL


ITEMS

ITEM_ID | PACK_ID | BRAND_ID
100     |  1      |   10
101     |  1      |  NULL
102     |  1      |   10

BRANDS
NAME | BRAND_ID
A    | 10
B    | 20
```

I want to write a query to list how many items are there in a package grouped by same brand. If the brand is not defined in the item it should get it from package.
Note: Brand_id in both package and items are nullable

My query is this

```
SELECT count (*) as count,p.descr as descr,b.name FROM [items] item 
inner join [package] p on item.pack_id= p.pack_id
inner join [brands] b on b.brand_id = item.brand_id or b.brand_id = p.brand_id
where p.pack_id = 1
group by b.name,p.descr
```

and my result is

```
COUNT | descr | NAME
2     | Shoes | a
3     | Shoes | B
```

whereas i expect the result to be something like this

```
COUNT | descr | NAME
2     | Shoes | a
1     | Shoes | B
```

could you please suggest what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ISNULL on your join condition:

```
SELECT count (*) as count,p.pack_id as pack_id,b.name FROM [items] item 
inner join [package] p on item.pack_id= p.pack_id
inner join [brands] b on b.brand_id = ISNULL(item.brand_id, p.brand_id)
where p.pack_id = 1
group by b.name,p.pack_id
```

Your OR was causing it to join to multiple rows, this should use the item by default and then fall back to the package.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to approach this by getting the brand for both the item *and* the package.  Then decide which one to use in the `select`:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, p.descr as descr, coalesce(bi.name, bp.name) as name
FROM [items] item inner join
     [package] p
     on item.pack_id= p.pack_id left join
     [brands] bi
     on bi.brand_id = item.brand_id left join
     brands bp
     on b.brand_id = p.brand_id
where p.pack_id = 1
group by coalesce(bi.name, bp.name), p.descr;
```

One key advantage to this approach is performance.  Databases tend to do a poor job when joins are on expression or `or` conditions.